# Why does scanf() not change line after input?

Tags: c++, vector, scanf

I want to input something like

```
1
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But with this code

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        vector <int> k, a, s;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%d", &k[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%d", &s[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d", (int)k[i], (int)a[i], (int)s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I can only input

```
1
3
1 2 3
```

scanf() does not change lines after the first for loop. How do I take in all the input?

Comment: The code only works if `n == 0`.  You may want to resize the vectors instead of accessing non-existent index positions.

Comment: @Eljay thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in this loop:

```
    vector <int> k, a, s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &k[i]);
    }
```

At the time you start running this loop, the vector `k` is empty. As a result, `&k[i]` is a pointer to a location in memory that isn't a part of the vector `k`, leading to undefined behavior. The same is true of the other loops as well.

If you'd like to use `scanf` this way, make sure to resize your vectors before reading into them. For example, you could declare them as

```
vector<int> k(n), a(n), s(n);
```

to ensure they have the right size.

Also, don't forget to check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that the reads are succeeding - that would be a good way, if the issue is indeed in `scanf`, to localize the error.